# Maximum length sequence with negative and positive subsequences

Tags: puzzle, popular-math

From ' mathematical puzzles' By Peter Winkler:

> " At the stockholders'  meeting the CEO presents month-by-month profits and losses and declares : ' Since the last meeting we have made a profit in every consecutive 8-month period!'

But a shareholder says 'we have also made a loss in every consecutive 5-month period'.

What is the maximum number of months that could have passed since the last meeting?"

In other words : find the maximum length sequence such that the sum of all 5-long consecutive  subsequences are negative and the sum of all 8-long consecutive  subsequences are positive

It will be less than 8*5=40 since otherwise there would be a simultaneous positive 8-long  partition and negative 5-long partition of the 40 months.

The solution in the book is rather elaborate (proof by induction that the solution is x+y-2 where x=8 and y=5) (and whilst the puzzles are great the writing style is obscure imho)

I am sure there must be a simpler solution .... but I cannot find one !

Comment: The problem is the *maximum* time since the last meeting. So you want us to prove that there is no solution better than 5,-8,5,5,-8,5,-8,5,5,-8,5 for the monthly results (any 5 months have 3 profits of 5 and 2 losses of -8 giving a net -1; any 8 months have 5 profits of 5 and 3 losses of -8 giving a net +1)? Or do you want a clearer way of *finding* the best solution?

Comment: Yes you are right. The problem is to find the maximum number of months since the last meeting. I have edited the question. I am seeking to find a clearer way of finding the solution, namely x+y-2, where x and y are relative  primes and where  in this case here x=8 and y=5

Comment: Yes you are right. Now edited.

Comment: @almagest: I'd be interested in seeing even just the solution given in the book, if it applies to the general case of coprime $x,y$!

Comment: @user3203476 The special case $x=11,y=7$ was a middling IMO question in 1977. So it was expected to take one of the best few dozen teenage mathematicians in the world at the time upwards of an hour to solve. It is basically combinatorics/elementary number theory, so more advanced maths is unlikely to help. You want a simple solution for the *general* case. I think you will require some luck in persuading someone to put in the necessary effort to find it (if it exists).  I looked at Winkler's proof. It is correct but would benefit from expansion.

Comment: i was hoping to find a solution based on copying the proof for the Erdős–Szekeres theorem in  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Szekeres_theorem . It is the only (possibly) related result I can find on this topic.